# Среднее арифметическое через reduce

Tags: javascript, map-reduce

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать простое вычисление среднего арифметического через метод reduce(или map).
Есть вот такой массив:

```
const data = [
  {name: "Ann", age: 24},
  {name: "Bred", age: 27},
  {name: "Grace", age: 21},
  {name: "Alex", age: 30},
  {name: "Robby", age: 25}
]
```

Нужно написать некоторую функцию, которая сможет высчитывать средний возраст этих людей.

Моё решение:

```
function calcAvgAge(array) {
  let sum = 0
  let cnt = 0
  let len = array.length
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += array[i].age
    cnt += 1
  }
  return sum / cnt
}
```

Очень громоздкое, и возможно не шибко производительное. Как написать проще средствами JavaScript?

Comment: По-моему, при всей «разжёванности», это вполне производительный вариант. Да и многословность не всегда плохо, краткие варианты бывает трудно читать, не стоит к ним стремиться ради самой краткости, особенно если будете работать в коллективе)

Comment: Я бы только cnt убрал. Он равен len

Comment: Поддержу, в командной разработке такой код более предпочтительный, он лучше читается. И может быть производительней, чем reduce (зависит от движка).

Answer (score 4):

```js
const data = [
  {name: "Ann", age: 24},
  {name: "Bred", age: 27},
  {name: "Grace", age: 21},
  {name: "Alex", age: 30},
  {name: "Robby", age: 25}
];

let avg = data.reduce((r,i) => r + i.age, 0) / (data.length || 1);
console.log(avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, сразу. reduce и всё. Ответ может накопить ошибку при сложении дробей. Но ответ Игоря также не лишён изъяна. Малая вероятность переполнения присутствует.

```js
const data = [
  {name: "Ann", age: 24},
  {name: "Bred", age: 27},
  {name: "Grace", age: 21},
  {name: "Alex", age: 30},
  {name: "Robby", age: 25}
];

let avg = data.reduce((r,i) => r + i.age/data.length, 0.0);
console.log(avg);
```

Comment: из-за накапливающейся ошибки результаты могут отличаться

Comment: Из-за переполнения также могут отличаться

Comment: могут, но с возрастами переполнение менее вероятно, чем накопление ошибки

Comment: Я написал по условию через reduce. Не претендую на 100%

Comment: претензия была не к reduce, а к частому сложению дробей :)

Comment: Думаете что ответ не имеет права на существование?

Comment: Написать в точности тот же ответ что и у Игоря думаю что это неверное решение. Так что написал свой

Comment: речь скорее про пояснение, что может что-то пойти не так

Comment: Добавил немного пояснения